# Issues writing to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have written the following code to test writing to a Firebase Realtime Database. It wrote data to the database once, but after that will do nothing. Currently, I am just trying to save the first name that the user enters on a form after they press the submit button.

```
<script type="module">
  // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-app.js";
  
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
  
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries      
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration      
    const firebaseConfig = {      
      apiKey: "AIzaSyAEGiSKDCg0nkrSxHshqxPEUWxtGI1NP7Q",      
      authDomain: "wrud-d63af.firebaseapp.com",      
      databaseURL: "https://wrud-d63af-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",      
      projectId: "wrud-d63af",      
      storageBucket: "wrud-d63af.appspot.com",      
      messagingSenderId: "491961850138",      
      appId: "1:491961850138:web:2468aff8d84e08c40ff4a3"      
    };
                
      // Initialize Firebase        
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      
      import {getDatabase, set, get, update, remove, ref, child} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.4.0/firebase-database.js"
      
      const db = getDatabase()
      
      var fname = document.getElementById("fname")
      var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn")
                
      function save(){            
          set(ref(db, "/"), {
              Name: fname.value
          })              
      }
                
      submitBtn.addEventListener('click', save)                 
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you already debug the code? If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?
 Is there any error message at that point?

Comment: I've done a bit of debugging and have not raised any errors as far as I can see. However, when looking at db variable I notice that the _instanceStarted property is set to false. Is this perhaps causing the issue?